# View did not update in Backbone with text! plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm just starting with Backbone.js. Now I'm trying to add item to cart that store in localStorage. This is my view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
  "underscore" ,
  "backbone" ,
  "text!templates/Cart/itemtemplate.html",
  "cart",
  "script"
],function($ , _ , Backbone , ItemTemplate, Cart , Script){

  var items = deserializeJSONToObj(localStorage.getItem("Cart"));
  var myCart = new Cart();
  var newItem = {
    "ID" : 348,
    "ItemCode" : "0352862925041",
    "PartNumber" : ""
    };

  if (!(items instanceof Array)) items = [];

  var promotionItem = _.template(ItemTemplate,{});

  var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize: function() {
          myCart.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
          $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
     },
     el: '.addToCart-form',
     events : {
         "click #addToCart" :  function(){
             myCart.addToCart(newItem);
             myCart.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
             $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
          }
     },
     render : function(){
        $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
     }
  });
 return HomeView;
```

When I click on Add To Cart button, the lable of items quantity `updateQtyLabel()` function is working, but the content html doesn't update with the new content that get from localStorage.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prepare your template with `var promotionItem = _.template(ItemTemplate,{});`
By passing a second argument, `{}`, you force interpolation of the variables and `promotionItem` is then a fixed string and won't change when the data is updated.

What you probably want to do is :

- prepare a compiled template :

  ```
  var promotionItem = _.template(ItemTemplate);
  ```
- obtain an updated HTML content :

  ```
  var html = promotionItem(myCart.toJSON());
  ```
- inject it into your element :

  ```
  this.$el.html(html);
  // in your case, $("#containernewpromotion").html(html);
  // but I'm really not fond of fixed DOM elements in modules
  ```

Comment: Never thought that was the problem. I just omitted `{}` from `promotionItem` like what you pointed at the first solution. It's working!